# Can I use Angular objects as parameters in a global javascript function not defined in the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to take a normal global javascript function and pass angular objects as its parameters?

```
    <ul ng-repeat="point in points">
       <li>
          <input onblur="foo(point)" type="text"/>
       </li>
    </ul>


    ...



    <script type="text/javascript">
         function foo(point){ .... }
    </script>
```

Where points is defined in the $scope.

Comment: This is really easy to try yourself; I think it doesn't work, but I may be wrong. If it doesn't, you can always do: `$scope.foo = foo;` (the RHS `foo` is the global).

Answer (score 0):

No this won't work, angular directives use the angular scope to resolve functions so they aren't "looking" at globals.  As Nikos says you can assign the scope variable to a global and then the directives would be able to properly call the function, generally speaking this isn't necessary.